# Binary search entering endless looping

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I want to binary search but the program is entering endless looping.
The program prints:

> Value = 10
>
> Value = 10
>
> Value = 10
>
> ...

How do I solve this problem?

```
public static void search(Node root, int data){
    while(root.data != data){
        if(data < root.data){
            search(root.left, data);
        }
        else if(data > root.data){
            search(root.right, data);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Value = " + root.data);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node root = null;
    root = add(root, 15);
    root = add(root, 3);
    root = add(root, 10);
    root = add(root, 20);
    root = add(root, 30);
    search(root, 10);
}
```

The Node class:

```
class Node {
    Node left;
    int data;
    Node right;

    Node(int data) {
        left = null;
        this.data = data;
        right = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your Node class and the add function?

Comment: Please edit your question and add an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Explain what you expected to happen and what actually happened. Currently, I can only guess that you are trying to use a recursive and an iterative solution at the same time. For the recursion, you are missing the breaking condition. For the iterative solution, you need to re-assign some variables for the while condition to become false.

Comment: class Node{
Node left;
int data;
Node right;
    Node(int data){
    left=null;
    this.data=data;
    right=null;
    }
}

Comment: add function is working.  I not good english sorry.

Comment: Can you provide the add function by editing the question?

Comment: I solved.Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the reason is that you are *not changing* `root` in this `while` loop, so it is **looping forever!** You might have intended to go down towards leaf nodes.

```
while(root.data != data){  //<<<<<<root not changing
    if(data < root.data){
        search(root.left, data);
    }
    else if(data > root.data){
        search(root.right, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it should work.

```
public static void search(Node root, int data)
{
    if(!root)
        return;
    else if(root.data == data)
    {
        System.out.println("Value = " + root.data);
    }
    else if(data < root.data)
        search(root.left, data);
    else
        search(root.right, data);
}
```